# Anyone ever been able to build a website with a moving video as a background?

Tags: flash, video, web

Trying to build a website where the background of the site is a video and then there would be an actual html page laid on top of it.

Comment: Isn't this like asking people to incriminate themselves? Ever use the BLINK tag either?

Comment: I already need something for my dizziness.

Comment: Thanks guys. Not really my choice. Designer and sales guy decided that would be a good idea.

Comment: @Chris tell them they are wrong and should take a stroll down similar accomplishments such as these http://superuser.com/questions/15798/worst-web-site-design-ever  having your website be different from everyone else is not a "good thing"

Comment: Also if they don't believe it's wrong tell them that you researched it and it is next to impossible to do it in a user friendly matter. (that way you don't lie :)

Comment: Right. I'm against this. But I'm doing the research anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, I wouldn't advice you either to do it...

Still, purely technically it's possible by layering the flash/content `divs` at `position:absolute` (with different `z-index`). The SWF itself also needs to have the `wmode` param set to `transparent`.

Comment: wmode can be opaque too. Setting the wmode is very important because otherwise flash essentially has z-index infinity. But ya this sounds like an awful idea.

Answer (score 0):

Ambient Project
Design Week 2008

http://designweek.ie/2008/index.html

Uses the div container to hold the flash video and an inner div to mask it by matching the width and height as well some other CSS *goodness*. Closest you will get without making it look like a disaster.

Use your dev tools (Firefox/Chrome) to take a look under their hood.

I have not tried the site in IE though.

Answer (score 0):

Consider presenting the user with an option to remove the Vid underlay?

It would be extremely easy to ruin people's faces when they go to the site once the vid underlay is implemented - but I've seen some amazing designs with vid underlays - esp. with flv cuepoints which are hopped between when interacting with various parts of the overlay content.

Don't be scared of the new requirement, be critical of the end result!

Oh, and I wonder what the scoop is with HTML5, for browsers capable of displaying open video formats natively, and whether that can then be done in full-screen mode, with other HTML5 elements over the top...

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say it won't be user friendly and would create dizziness. It all depends to the graphics and video combination used. Very mellow changes might create an interesting effect.

I would put the transparent swf in a div and animate the div with jQuery.